# EF Code First Configuration Duplicating Records

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

So I'm attempting to populate a table with seed data in EF5.  I have an Enum of all 50 states and DC.  I also have a lookup table of RequestTypes with IDs 1-6.  It would be something like this:

```
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
| Id |  State   |  SurveyId   | RequestType|
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Alabama  |           0 |          1 |
|  2 | Alabama  |           0 |          2 |
|  3 | Alabama  |           0 |          3 |
|  4 | Alabama  |           0 |          4 |
|  5 | Alabama  |           0 |          5 |
|  6 | Alabama  |           0 |          6 |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
```

The model that represents this table:

```
public class StateSurveyAssignment{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public long RequestTypeId { get; set; }
    public long SurveyId { get; set; }
}
```

And the code to seed the database in the Configuration.cs:

```
foreach (var state in Enum.GetValues(typeof(State))) {
     foreach (var type in context.RequestTypes){
          context.StateSurveyAssignments.AddOrUpdate(
                ssa => ssa.Id,
                new StateSurveyAssignment{
                    State = state.ToString(),
                    RequestTypeId = type.Id
                }
           );

       }
 }
```

My problem is that instead of updating/doing nothing to unchanged records, the seed method is duplicating each row.  I've attempted to manually set the Id but had no luck.

EDIT:

This is what the database duplication looks like:

```
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
| Id |  State   |  SurveyId   | RequestType|
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Alabama  |           0 |          1 |
|  2 | Alabama  |           0 |          2 |
|  3 | Alabama  |           0 |          3 |
|  4 | Alabama  |           0 |          4 |
|  5 | Alabama  |           0 |          5 |
|  6 | Alabama  |           0 |          6 |
| ...|   ...    |     ...     |      ...   |
|307 | Alabama  |           0 |          1 |
|308 | Alabama  |           0 |          2 |
|309 | Alabama  |           0 |          3 |
|310 | Alabama  |           0 |          4 |
|311 | Alabama  |           0 |          5 |
|312 | Alabama  |           0 |          6 |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
```

**My Solution**

I swear I'd tried setting my own Id at some point but tried it again per the answer and it seems to have worked.  My final solution:

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (var state in Enum.GetValues(typeof(State))) {
        foreach (var type in context.RequestTypes){
             context.StateSurveyAssignments.AddOrUpdate(
                   ssa => ssa.Id,
                   new StateSurveyAssignment{
                        Id = counter,
                        State = state.ToString(),
                        RequestTypeId = type.Id
                    }
              );
          counter++;
         }
}
```

Comment: What is `AddOrUpdate`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Interesting.. didn't know about that, thanks

Comment: Can you show what is your actual result? Is it `6` Missouri records with same `RequestType` equal to `1`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Not quite.  It's another set of State 1-6, but I've updated the question with a better explanation.

Comment: Is `Id` an identity column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that the `Id` property in your `StateSurveyAssignment` class is an Identity column in the database. 
This means that each row is not unique.

For example you try to insert the following several times using `AddOrUpdate()`

```
var model = new StateSurveyAssignment
{
    State = "Alabama",
    RequestTypeId = 1L,
    SurveyId = 0L
};
```

Then each entry would have a different `Id` and thus you'll have duplicates.